# .h implementation file won't recognise my UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

**UPDATE: All working now, forgot to link up the view in the .xib file.**

I have imported my view controller's implementation files like so;

```
#import "TopicsListParentViewController.h"
```

When I write:

```
TopicsListParentViewController *tlparentview;
```

There are no errors at first, but then when building the project, this error appears:

**Unknown type name 'TopicsListParentViewController'; did you mean 'TopicsListViewController'?**

Why is this and how can I fix it? Here's a screenshot to help you imagine the scene more accurately:

[image]

**EDIT: Here are the .h and .m for "TopicsListParentViewController"**

**.h Implementation File:**

```
//
//  TopicsListParentViewController.h
//
//  Created by James Anderson on 27/04/2012.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 PixelBit Apps Ltd. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SuperChatAppDelegate.h"
#import "TopicsListViewController.h"

@interface TopicsListParentViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIView *parentview;

IBOutlet TopicsListViewController *topicsListViewController;

}

@end
```

**.m Implementation File:**

```
//
//  TopicsListParentViewController.m
//
//  Created by James Anderson on 27/04/2012.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 PixelBit Apps Ltd. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TopicsListParentViewController.h"

@implementation TopicsListParentViewController 

-(void)viewDidLoad
{

[parentview addSubview:topicsListViewController.tableView];
NSLog(@"Added subview");

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation ==     UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: can you show us the .h and .m of TopicsListParentViewController..?

Comment: check your file name...it might get changed...

Comment: check your class name in TopicsListParentViewController.h too.

Comment: R u drag this file from another project for not?

Comment: edited now and no, I didn't drag the file from another project - I created it from within the project

Comment: All working now, forgot to link up the view in the .xib file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check to make sure your files properly have.

```
 @interface TopicsListParentViewController
  ...
 @end
```

and

```
 @implementation TopicsListParentViewController
  ...
 @end
```

Comment: My .h file doesn't have this? Should it and if so, where?

Comment: @objc-obsessive, he's referring to the .h and .m of `TopicsListParentViewController` having those lines.

Comment: All working now, forgot to link up the view in the .xib file.

Answer (score 0):

Check endy's post + check if you put your TopicsListParentViewController into your project's target -> aware of adding your files just to tests target

Comment: Yes, it is in my project's target

Answer (score 0):

I guess your Xcode's derived data directory is corrupted.

Delete it and try a clean build.